# Bower Loading devDependencies in Production?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, leaflet, bower

### Short Version

My project requires angular-leaflet, and angular-leaflet has a [long list of devDependencies](https://github.com/tombatossals/angular-leaflet-directive/blob/master/bower.json), including jQuery 2. I don't want jQuery 2--I want jQuery 1.x. How can I get bower to ignore the devDependencies of angular-leaflet and let me use jQuery 1?

### Long Version

I am using bower 1.2.8. Here is a minimal bower.json that reproduces the problem for me:

```
{
  "name": "bower-test",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "1.x",
    "angular": "1.2.x",
    "angular-leaflet": "0.7.x"
  }
}
```

Running `bower install` results in the following error:

```
Unable to find a suitable version for jquery, please choose one:
    1) jquery#1.x which resolved to 1.11.0 and has bower-test as dependants
    2) jquery#2.1.0 which resolved to 2.1.0 and has angular-leaflet#0.7.5 as dependants
    3) jquery#>= 1.9.0 which resolved to 2.1.0 and has bootstrap#3.0.3 as dependants
```

At the very least, I expected `bower install --production` to ignore devDependencies in angular-leaflet. But here's the result (identical to above):

```
Unable to find a suitable version for jquery, please choose one:
    1) jquery#1.x which resolved to 1.11.0 and has bower-test as dependants
    2) jquery#2.1.0 which resolved to 2.1.0 and has angular-leaflet#0.7.5 as dependants
    3) jquery#>= 1.9.0 which resolved to 2.1.0 and has bootstrap#3.0.3 as dependants
```

Why is bower not ignoring the devDependencies of angular-leaflet? Is there a way to make it do so?

Comment: If you enter "1" for the choice it seems to use 1.11.0 as you wanted. Can you confirm this?

Comment: Confirmed. Unfortunately, when putting angular-leaflet into production with everything else I was using it did the same sort of thing for other conflicts and was loading way too much. So I guess the main point was trying to figure out how to ignore devDependencies.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think the solution you are looking for is the `resolutions` section of `bower.json` though 
as to why `devDependencies` of your `dependencies` are even being analyzed is not clear to me.

```
{
  "name": "bower-test",
  "dependencies": {
    "jquery": "1.x",
    "angular": "1.2.x",
    "angular-leaflet": "0.7.x"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "jquery": "1.x"
  }
}
```

<del>Perhaps this is a slight difference from `npm` in that doing `bower install xyz` includes `devDependencies` unless the `-p` or `--production` parameter is specified, but even if it is specified it doesn't seem to get passed on to `dependencies` -- perhaps this is a bug.</del>

**UPDATE:** The problem seems to be related to this particular package/setup using `angular-leaflet`. Other components do not have this issue. For example,  `bower install webmaker-analytics` just fetches `webmaker-analytics`, not `qunit` even though it was listed in this package's [`devDependencies`](https://github.com/mozilla/webmaker-analytics/blob/master/bower.json).

Comment: I think you're right that it's something to do with the particular modules. I got busy on other work for a couple weeks and when I came back the problem had just disappeared, even without updating bower to the most recent version. I kinda hate not knowing why, though. But thanks for your help!

Comment: If your curiosity is killing you then you may benefit from looking through the `CHANGELOG` entries for these projects over the last month. Personally, however, when things are working the way they are supposed to I wouldn't recommend spending any time digging into it unless its code that you are or will be in some way responsible for maintaining (i.e. not an actively 3rd party project that you're pulling in as a dependency).